# NullPointerException for LatLng GPS location

Tags: java, android, google-maps, nullpointerexception, android-gps

I am using Google Maps to obtain my current location and display a red marker on my location. So far it only the `mMap.setMyLocation(true);` works for my location. I am getting NullPointerException for the object `userLocation` towards the end of my code and the output to the console for `userLocation`is null too.

How do I set the userLocation as soon as I load the map ?

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;

    LocationManager locationManager;

    LocationListener locationListener;
    LatLng userLocation;
    private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;
    public  float DEFAULT_ZOOM = 15f;
    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        if (requestCode == 1) {

            if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    {

                        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);

                    }

                }

            }

        }

    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
            }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;
        locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        locationListener = new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

                userLocation = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());

                mMap.clear();
                mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(userLocation).title("Your Location"));
                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(userLocation));
                System.out.println("the latitude onLocationChanged is "+ userLocation.latitude);


            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

            }
        };



        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 23) {
        try {
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
        }
        catch (SecurityException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        } else {

            if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1);

            } else {

                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1, 1, locationListener);
              //  LatLng latLng = new LatLng(40.741895,-73.989308);
                mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            //outputs the latitude is null 
                System.out.println("the latitude is "+userLocation);
              mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(userLocation).title("Your Location"));
                mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(userLocation));


            }


        }


    }


}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't.  Getting a location takes time.  It won't be available until your callback is called, which means you can't load it until then.  You could try calling getLastKnownLocation, but it will return null the majority of the time as well.  The best solution is not to rely on it until the callback is made.

Comment: So how do I get the callback ? What is the name of the function ?

Comment: @Hazed2.0 you don't call it, you wait till system calls it

Comment: Its the onLocationChanged function of the location listener you pass in.  You have one written there, so long as you have your permissions ready it should be ok.

Comment: so is the code at the very end of the script where I have called mMap.addMarker() etc. not necessary then ?

Comment: Also the call back is not working because onLocationChanged function does seem to be getting called, i've logged it and nothing is being outputted at all. This is very strange because mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true) is working completely fine and displaying my location with the blue dot.

Answer (score 0):

on method, OnMapReady use this code

```
if (!mMap.isMyLocationEnabled())
        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    Location userLocation = getLocation();
```

and use this method to get the last location if you want it

```
public Location getLocation() {
        LocationManager lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        Location myLocation = lm.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
        if (myLocation == null) {
            Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
            criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_COARSE);
            String provider = lm.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
            myLocation = lm.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
        }
        return myLocation;
    }
```

**Note**: `GPS_PROVIDER` does not work indoors, so you should try it outdoor.

maybe you want to start the callback just if the last location before more than one minute. use this code

```
if (System.currentTimeMillis()-myLocation.getTime()>60000){
 locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1, 1, locationListener);

       };
```